# Optimal Control: Can I express a Macroeconomic model as a state space control system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, economics, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

Both Recursive Macroeconomic models and Control theory problems use ideas from the calculus of variations to estimate unknown functions. In the case of a Macroeconomic model--as shown below--that unknown function is the output of an optimization problem. In the case of state space control--for a linear system--the unknown function is also the output of an optimization problem. **Hence I was wondering if there is a way to express a Macroeconomic model problem in a state space form and solve the problem using Control theory numerical solvers?**

Recursive Macroeconomic models rely on the simple formulation below. $u(c_{t+j})$ is the utility function of an individual given a consumption level of $c_{t+j}$ indexed by time $t+j$. The equation is given below. There is often a budget constraint in there as well

$$
\max_{c_{t+j}, i_{t+j}} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \beta^j u(c_{t+j})\\
$$
The equation is subject to the following budget constraint, where $F(k)$ is the production function for the economy--meaning the total output of the economy.

$$
\text{subject to:} \quad c_{t+j} + i_{t+j} = F(k_{t+j})
$$

further the production function is subject to the additional constraint:
$$
k_{t+j+1} = (1-\delta)k_{t+j} + i_{t+j}
$$

The parameter $\delta$ is the rate of depreciation of equipment, $i$ is the amount of investment in the economy--to buy more capital, and $k$ is the amount of capital equipment in the economy to produce goods. Now there is more sophistication to this system, but this is the essential flavor of the problem, as per Greenwood and Marto (manuscript). The usual approach is to add more constraint equations that model production in the economy, and taxation, etc.

These problems may be solved analytically using the Euler equation (Economist's term for the Euler-Lagrange equation), but numerically they are solved with dynamic programming methods like value iteration, policy iteration, etc.

In contrast, the usual state space optimal control problems are formulated as below:

$$
\dot{x} = Ax(t) + Bv(t)
$$
$$
\dot{y} = Cx(t) + Dv(t)
$$

Note that I used $v$ here instead of the more common $u$, to disambiguate between the utility function and control function. These control problems are also solved with dynamic programming methods, just as the economic problems above.

Hence, I was wondering if I can express the Economics problem as a state space control problem. The control variables, like $c, h$ would be set to the control function $v(\cdot)$.

**UPDATE**
I updated the equations as per feedback from some of the viewers. I provided a bit more detail on the model, compared to the original simpler formulation. I also corrected some of the subscripts, etc.

Comment: How is the constraint relevant to the maximization? I don't see that $k$ has any influence on the function to be maximized, is this correct?

Comment: @SampleTime Oh you are totally write. I have to adjust that. I was cobbling together some different notes to write the function and forgot to adjust the variable. Let me fix it.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what the problem is. The original problem is already in state-space form, but in discrete-time while the state-space form you give at the end is in continuous-time. The issue here is that you have not clearly defined you input which seems to be $c_t$. It seems that $i_t$ depends on $c_t$ either in a static or in dynamic fashion. Moreover, it is not clear how $k_t$ plays a role in the problem. So, you will have to provide more details. But all in all, it is likely that you already have an optimal control problem with dynamical constraints in state-space form.

Comment: Ok so the post has been edited. But the issue now is that it is not clear what your decision input is.

Comment: @KBS yes sorry for the confusion. I was trying to keep the model as simple as possible and stripped out the complexity. I could write economic model in continuous time form as well, with no trouble. People usually solve it in both ways. 

The usual way the problem is setup is that the consumption variable $c$ is dependent upon the production of products in the economy, $f(k, l)$. So the constraint on the $k$ variable would affect the amount of production which affects consumption.

Comment: @KBS I found a good simplication of the model in a book by Marto and Greenwood. Hopefully that will resolve my confusing presentation. Let me adjust the equations above to include the production function.

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to write down equations as while those models may be clear to you, this will not be the case for the vast majority of people here. You will have to clearly state what the state is, what the control input is, and what the parameters are.

Comment: @KBS Okay, I took this from a different book, but same model. I laid out the simple set of constraints. Basically the initial condition is $k_{t+0}$ which is the initial amount of capital equipment in the economy. From that equipment a factory can produce output according to $F(k_{t+j})$. Then the amount of consumption is subject to the amount of production and investment with represent the amount of money that users have to consume with. The $t+j$ notation seemed a bit confusing to me, but I copied this verbatim from the book.

Comment: To make things clear, we can choose $c_{t+j}$ and $i_{t+j}$, correct?

Comment: @KBS yes, that is correct. So we want to find the function or vector $c_{t+j}, i_{t+j}$ that maximizes the objective. We can also assume that the functions are well behaved and have a single maximum value. There is a contraction mapping theorem that provides the mathematical sufficiency condition.

Comment: Then, you problem is essentially a discrete-time optimal control problem and you can eliminate the equality constraint and obtain the state-space system $k_{t+j+1} = (1-\delta)k_{t+j} +F(k_{t+j}) - c_{t+j}$. Now, you have only $c$ as control input.

Comment: @KBS okay, so that makes a lot more sense. So I will try to formulate a code out of this and see if I can get it to run. Then I can compare it to some known solutions for the same problems. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I guess you will have some inequality constraints to consider to ensure the positivity of some variables.

Comment: Yes that is true. I think one common trick that economists use is just to log the variables. That way things stay positive. I think that should work with these models as well. If taking logs does not work, then I can include the inequality constraints directly.